# Why does function being linear imply it can be represented as matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices

In the video where 3blue1brown explains [determinants](https://youtu.be/BaM7OCEm3G0?t=395), this point in question is brought up at 6:35  but what is the intuition/ justification for this statement?

Comment: Matrices, at their core, can be viewed as blocks of information conveying what each basis vector of a space is mapped to. For any such matrix, there exists exactly one linear map that satisfies those conditions. Hence, we identify matrices with finite-dimensional linear maps.

Comment: The intuition is: you follow what happens to a basis under the linear map.